# How do I create a dynamic back button using Next.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, url-routing

I know how to create a regular back button. But I want to create a button that takes you back one step in the URL and not to the previous page. In that way I can use the button on different places and dont have to change anything in the code. But I cant figure it out. I am a newbie.

example: if I am at *stackoverflow.com* and I navigate myself directly to a question like *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask* I want to be able to click the backbutton and end up in *https://stackoverflow.com/questions* So I can view other questions.

I am using TypeScript,React,Next languanges. So I can only use a script from those. I found a similar question here but they are using Angular and I dont know how to convert that to Next.js

I appreciate any help, clue whatever you can help me with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make ad hoc solution with simple string processing:

```
const BackButton = () => {
   const { asPath } = useRouter();
   const backUrl = asPath.slice(0, asPath.lastIndexOf('/'));

   return <a href={backUrl}> Back </a>;
}
```

If you have basePath or locale then you can concatenate them to asPath.

Comment: Thanks alot!! I cant upvote your comment since im too new on this site. It took me a while to figure out what you did but as I understand it you are making it return to the last /, Which is brilliant. Do you have any tips for me on what to study so I can think like you lol. The asPath was new to me, so im gonna read more on it.